# How to get image file with other parameters in node.js using typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am getting an image file and other parameters in a single form. I am using routing-controller (npm library) decorator to get the file `@UploadedFile("image") file?: any` and getting other params in body `@Body({ required: true }) review: ReviewInput`. Is there any good way to get these params?
`ReviewInput` is my defined type which contains the string params following is the code where I am getting params:

```
@Post("/review")
async addReview(
@Body({ required: true }) review: ReviewInput,
@UploadedFile("image") file?: any,) {

return AddReviewsUsecase.execute(review, file);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@BodyParam()` if you have few parameters in body.
Example:

```
@Post("/review")
async addReview(
    @BodyParam() review: string,
    @BodyParam() rating: number,
    @UploadedFile("image") file?: any,
) {
    return AddReviewsUsecase.execute(review, file);
}
```

Comment: In bodyparam should we give the name of the parameter as an argument? as BodyParam("review") review: string.

Comment: Yes, its right. You have to give argument.